# Where do geo location services get their database content from?

Tags: geolocation, dataset

We've been needing to implement some geo-location service integration for some of our products. There are a lot of 3rd party companies that offer both free and paid geo location services and databases that are updated sometimes constantly and sometimes once a month.

Where do these services get the geo location information for their databases they distribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depends on the type of geolocation. if you mean ip<>country/city [eg www.maxmind.com] - basic information can be found in the whois records maintained by the network operators/[regional internet registries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_Registry). for instance: http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/?host=64.34.119.12

i suppose it's possible to clean/normalize this data semi-automatically.

if you mean mac address<>geographical coordinates - most probably just spying on the users [with their consent.. or without] - either gathering the information from applications running on mobile devices with gps and wifi onboard or by 'war driving' around - like the google earth street view teams.

Comment: I mean't IP <> Country/City. So these services don't sit there and automatically requery whois results for every single IP address combination every day/week/month in order to determine if some locations have changed, do they?

Comment: at least ripe [and probably other RIRs] provide dump of their databases. http://www.ripe.net/data-tools/db/faq/faq-db -> ftp://ftp.ripe.net/ripe/dbase/split

Comment: Thanks but my question is, where do these companies (like Ripe) get their data? They obviously aren't pulling them out of thin air. Is there some high level RSS feeds they pull their information from or something like that?

Comment: RIPE is authority. it assigns ip address ranges, network operators update and submit to it records. actually - at this stage it would be better if you ask identical question on the serverfault.com - there'll be more competent people that can tell you more about the WHOIS database.

Answer (score 2):

We get our data from public enities:

- ISO: International Standards Organization
- BGN: US Board on Geographic Names
- UNGEGN: United Nations Group of Experts on Geographic Names
- PCGN: UK Permanent Committee on Geographic Names
- FAO: United Nations Food and Argriculture Organization
- FIPS: US Federal Information Processing System
- ITU: The International Teleccmmunication Union

Then update our MySQL database monthly.  Our service is currently FREE!

http://nwstartups.com/api/geo/country.php